# Join UTF-8 strings

Tags: javascript, string, utf-8

I want to join some UTF-8 strings together, Any ideas?

e.g:

> Input: س + ل + ا + م
>
> Output: سلام

Comment: you should probably mention what language you're trying to do this in.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Oh sorry, I'm trying with Arabic.

Comment: i meant, what programming language | EDIT: I just saw your tags, but you should still make it obvious on your header or something

Comment: @TaylorFlores JavaScript, Also this question created on JavaScript thread.

Comment: @TaylorFlores That's the reason for tags. So titles/descriptions aren't flooded with the language. Unless it's a combination of languages in the questions and tags, then it should be explained more. Although an example with the language of what's expected in this question would've been helpful (not just text)

Comment: Just concatenate the with the `+` operator? Where is your problem? Can you show us some sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript you can do `var output = 'س + ل + ا + م'.split(' + ').join('');`. Just replace what is separating the characters in the split function.

Comment: True, but the logic applies the same. I edited for clarity. Thanks.